# Why can I not 'pack' or 'grid' an ImageTk.PhotoImage in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code:

```
my_img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\talha\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Tkinter\My First Tkinter Program\Mt Everest.jpg").resize((500,500))
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_img)
my_img.pack()
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

Answer (score 1):

An `ImageTk.PhotoImage` isn't a `tkinter` widget, but can be made a part of one. It will then be the created widget you will want to `pack()` or `grid()`.

Below is an example of putting one on a `tkinter.Label` widget (and then  packing that):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

filepath = r"C:\Users\talha\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Tkinter\My First Tkinter Program\Mt Everest.jpg"

root = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open(filepath).resize((500, 500))  # PIL image object.
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)  # Convert to tkinter PhotoImage.
my_label = tk.Label(image=my_img)  # Put it on a Label.
my_label.img = my_img  # Attach reference to image to prevent its deletion.
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```